# Adding cordova plugin for windows universal with ibm mobile first

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, win-universal-app

We are developing windows universal application with IBM Mobile First(version 7.0), Can anyone tell me the steps to add an existing or developing cordova plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start with mentioning your MobileFirst version...

Answer (score 2):

There is no separate cordova plugin for windows in MFP 7.0 Version. If you are looking for Hybrid Development for Windows Universal Application, I suggest you to start with ["Getting Started Blog"](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/hybrid-tutorials/)

Comment: I need to add keypad cordova plugin for windows(Windows universal environment in IBM MF ) , Can you please let me know how to add.

Comment: @KamakshiReddy I hope [this blog](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/) explains you on how to add third party plugins in your hybrid project.

Comment: this is working for all platform except windows universal . if possible Can you please try it for windows universal and let me know. It helps a lot

Comment: it doesn't have config.xml file.